# iOS Notification Trigger: Every Two Months & Every Three Months

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to create notifications that repeat every two months or every three months, depending on the user's selection.

I can successfully create one that sends a notification two/three months after the user makes their initial choice, but the 'repeats:' part is stuck on that day, so it will just repeat once a year at whatever two/three months after their initial selection was.

How can I create a notification that repeats every two/three months? Is there a way to repeat the dateRequest() function call each time the notification is triggered? That way, I could continually get a notification every two/three months because the call would be refreshed.

Here's my code to create the 'every two months' notification. The three months code is essentially the same.

```
var components = DateComponents()

    //if it's January - October, send notification two months after the current month
if Date().currentMonth()! < 11 {

    components.month = Date().currentMonthPlusTwo()

    //if it's November, send notification in January
} else if Date().currentMonth()! == 11 {

    components.month = 1

    //if it's December, send notification in February
} else if Date().currentMonth()! == 12 {

    components.month = 2

}

components.day = Date().dayOfMonth()
components.hour = 14
components.minute = 30 //every two months at 2:30pm

NotificationService.shared.dateRequest(with: components, contactName: storedContacts[key].key, identifier: storedContacts[key].value[10])
```

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As a workaround you could create multiple two/three months notifications ahead of time.

Comment: you have to  add multiple notification for 2/3 months for the time you want may be 2 year or 3 years.for example if you want notification after 2 months for next 3 year you have to add 18 notification for every 2 months